# NSString constrainedToSize method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, algorithm, cocoa, core-text

Not to get confused with the `NSString sizeWithFont` method that returns a `CGSize`, what I'm looking for is a method that returns an `NSString` constrained to a certain `CGSize`. The reason I want to do this is so that when drawing text with `Core Text`, I can get append an ellipses (...) to the end of the string. I know `NSString's drawInRect` method does this for me, but I'm using `Core Text`, and `kCTLineBreakByTruncatingTail` truncates the end of *each line* rather than the end of the string.

There's [this method that I found](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/truncate-an-nsstring-and-append-an-ellipsis-respecting-the-font-size.html) that truncates a string to a certain *width*, and it's not that hard to change it to make it work for a `CGSize`, but the algorithm is unbelievably slow for long strings, and is practically unusable. (It took over 10 seconds to truncate a long string). There has to be a more "computer science"/mathematical algorithm way to do this faster. Anyone daring enough to try to come up with a faster implementation?

**Edit:** I've managed to make this in to a binary algorithm:

```
-(NSString*)getStringByTruncatingToSize:(CGSize)size string:(NSString*)string withFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    int min = 0, max = string.length, mid;
    while (min < max) {
        mid = (min+max)/2;

        NSString *currentString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(min, mid - min)];
        CGSize currentSize = [currentString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(size.width, MAXFLOAT)];

        if (currentSize.height < size.height){
            min = mid + 1;
        } else if (currentSize.height > size.height) {
            max = mid - 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

   NSMutableString *finalString = [[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, min)] mutableCopy];
   if(finalString.length < self.length)
         [finalString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(finalString.length - 3, 3) withString:@"..."];

   return finalString;
}
```

The problem is that this sometimes cuts the string too short when it has room to spare. I think this is where that last condition comes in to play. How do I make sure it doesn't cut off *too much*?

Comment: Working from what you've got there, just as a first pass maybe you could try turning that into a binary search instead of linear?

Comment: You need to keep searching unless you find an exact match (unlikely) or until you drop out of the bottom of the loop, at which point `min >= max` and one of those values is the index you want.

Comment: Ok I re-edited it. As far as my testing goes it works great. Does anything look wrong with it?

Comment: Looks OK, but I don't get why you are comparing height and not width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good news! There is a "computer science/mathematical way" to do this faster.

The [example you link to](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/truncate-an-nsstring-and-append-an-ellipsis-respecting-the-font-size.html) does a linear search: it just chops one character at a time from the end of the string until it's short enough. So, the amount of time it takes will scale linearly with the length of the string, and with long strings it will be really slow, as you've discovered.

However, you can easily apply a **binary search** technique to the string. Instead of starting at the end and dropping off one character at a time, you start in the middle:

```
THIS IS THE STRING THAT YOU WANT TO TRUNCATE
                       ^
```

You compute the width of "THIS IS THE STRING THAT". If it is too wide, you move your test point to the midpoint of the space on the left. Like this:

```
THIS IS THE STRING THAT YOU WANT TO TRUNCATE
          ^            |
```

On the other hand, if it isn't wide enough, you move the test point to the midpoint of the other half:

```
THIS IS THE STRING THAT YOU WANT TO TRUNCATE
                       |         ^
```

You repeat this until you find the point that is just under your width limit. Because you're dividing your search area in half each time, you'll never need to compute the width more than log2 N times (where N is the length of the string) which doesn't grow very fast, even for very long strings.

To put it another way, if you double the length of your input string, that's only one additional width computation.

Starting with [Wikipedia's binary search sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Iterative), here's an example. Note that since we're not looking for an exact match (you want largest that will fit) the logic is slightly different.

```
int binary_search(NSString *A, float max_width, int imin, int imax)
{
  // continue searching while [imin,imax] is not empty
  while (imax >= imin)
    {
      /* calculate the midpoint for roughly equal partition */
      int imid = (imin + imax) / 2;

      // determine which subarray to search
      float width = ComputeWidthOfString([A substringToIndex:imid]);
      if      (width < max_width)
        // change min index to search upper subarray
        imin = imid + 1;
      else if (width > max_width )
        // change max index to search lower subarray
        imax = imid - 1;
      else
        // exact match found at index imid
        return imid;
  }
  // Normally, this is the "not found" case, but we're just looking for
  // the best fit, so we return something here.
  return imin;
}
```

You need to do some math or testing to figure out what's the right index at the bottom, but it's definitely `imin` or `imax`, plus or minus one.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I was able to get something going, but I can't seem to figure out how I would do the third step: "On the other hand, if it isn't wide enough, you move the test point to the midpoint of the other half:" How would I know if it isn't wide enough?